# Creating a bean after calling a method Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am wrinting a simple app and came across a problem that would be solved if I called a method before a specific bean was initialized/created, is something like that possible? I want to call generateSimulation() method in Simulation() method which is called by a controller and by using aop I want to call Simulation_parameters_day_1() before generateSimulation() but it won't work with simple call on said method in Simulation() method (commented line in simulation method) what I have to do is make a bean out of generateSimulation() but then it will be called by Spring  immdiately after creation, I  want to call Simulation() method then  immdiately after that meake a bean out of generateSimulation() and then aop will call the Simulation_parameters_day_1() method before generateSimulation()

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.2
 

com.example
demo
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
demo
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>11</java.version>

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EntityScan("Terative.Entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("Terative.Repositories")
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class Simulation_service {


    private final SimulationRepository simulationRepository;
    private final SimulationsValuesRepository simulationsValuesRepository;


    public void Simulation(String N, Long P, Long I, Double R, Double M, Long Ti, Long Tm, Long Ts) {

        var simulation = Simulation.builder()
                .simulation_Name(N)
                .population_Size(P)
                .initial_infected_number(I)
                .how_many_one_infects(R)
                .mortality_Rate(M)
                .number_of_days_to_recovery(Ti)
                .number_of_days_to_Death(Tm)
                .simulation_time(Ts)
                .build();
        simulationRepository.save(simulation);
        //generateSimulation();
    }


    //@PostConstruct
    @Bean
    @MyAnnotation
    public void generateSimulation() {
        for (int i = 2; i <= simulationRepository.getById(1L).getSimulation_time(); i++) {

            var simulation_values = SimulationsValues.builder()
                    .healthy_prone_to_infection(simulationsValuesRepository.getById((long) i - 1)
                            .getHealthy_prone_to_infection() - simulationsValuesRepository.getById((long) i - 1)
                            .getNumber_of_infected() - simulationsValuesRepository.getById((long) i - 1)
                            .getRegained_health_and_immunity() - simulationsValuesRepository.getById((long) i - 1).getDead())


                    .regained_health_and_immunity(0L)
                    .number_of_infected((long) (simulationsValuesRepository.getById((long) i - 1)
                            .getNumber_of_infected() * 
      simulationRepository.getById((long) i - 1).getHow_many_one_infects()))

                    .dead(0L)
                    .build();
            simulationsValuesRepository.save(simulation_values);
        }

    }
}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
@Aspect
public class Day_One {


    private final SimulationRepository simulationRepository;
    private final SimulationsValuesRepository simulationsValuesRepository;


    @Pointcut("@annotation(Terative.Annotations.MyAnnotation)")
    public void MyAnnotationMethod() {
    }


    @Before("MyAnnotationMethod()")
    public Long Simulation_parameters_day_1() {
        var simulation = simulationRepository.getById(1L);
        var simulation_values = SimulationsValues.builder()
                .healthy_prone_to_infection(simulation.getPopulation_Size() - simulation.getInitial_infected_number())
                .regained_health_and_immunity(0L)
                .number_of_infected(simulation.getInitial_infected_number())
                .dead(0L)
                .build();
        simulationsValuesRepository.save(simulation_values);
        return simulation_values.getId();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only needed to put @Lazy above the @Bean method and @Configuration above class, @Lazy initializes a bean only when a method with @Bean annonation is called

```
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    @MyAnnotation
    public void generateSimulation() {
        for (int i = 2; i <= simulationRepository.getById(1L).getSimulation_time(); i++) {

            var simulation_values = SimulationsValues.builder()
                    .healthy_prone_to_infection(simulationsValuesRepository.getById((long) i - 1)
                            .getHealthy_prone_to_infection() - simulationsValuesRepository.getById((long) i - 1)
                            .getNumber_of_infected() - simulationsValuesRepository.getById((long) i - 1)
                            .getRegained_health_and_immunity() - simulationsValuesRepository.getById((long) i - 1).getDead())


                    .regained_health_and_immunity(0L)
                    .number_of_infected((long) (simulationsValuesRepository.getById((long) i - 1)
                            .getNumber_of_infected() * 
      simulationRepository.getById((long) i - 1).getHow_many_one_infects()))

                    .dead(0L)
                    .build();
            simulationsValuesRepository.save(simulation_values);
        }

    }
```